# Is it possible to write data into csv files and then use SSRS reports with SQL queries to view reports?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

All of my data is in Csv files and I wanted to ask if it is possible to display the data as SSRS reports.  Is it possible to achieve this without extract data from csv files and dumping into SQL DB.

Answer (score 1):

Possible? Certainly.

As easy as you hope it will be? Probably not.

There is no out-of-the-box connection from SSRS to .csv files. So you'll need to get the data into SSRS somehow. If you are doing client side SSRS, this means creating a dataset from the .csv. If you are using a server based report, then you need to create a [Data Processing Entension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152816.aspx). They aren't too hard to write, but you definitely need to be familiar with the .NET language of your choice.

If the task of reporting on .csv files was given to me, I would implement a SSIS package to import the files to a SQL database, and then write the report against the database. This would provide better performance and more flexibility and also be quicker to implement than reporting directly on the .csv files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using your CSV file as an ODBC data source within your report?